# Android reverse tethering through Whonix Workstation in virtualbox?

Tags: whonix, android, virtual-machine

I need to connect my android phone to tor network.
I tried orbot, for some reason only orfox is working, other apps don't work - I set all setting to "torify" ALL apps but they don't connect.

So I want to try to connect android phone to tor via  reverse tethering usb connection. I have whonix installed in Virtualbox.

I tried reverse tethering app "reverse tether" (in the screenshot) and test connected to non tor virtual machine and it connects OK, but as soon as I route that VM to whonix GW, reverse tether app don't connect.
(Both whonix GW and WS connects to tor)

I am not very knowledgeable about networks, so if someone can help what IP addresses (desired IP, gateway IP) should I set in reverse tether app in android, so it make it connect and work? Or which settings should be changed so I can finally connect android to Tor?

[image: Screenshot: Linux connection vs Reserve tether app in android]

Answer (score 1):

This is [unsupported](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Unsupported).

Full disclosure:
I am a developer of Whonix.

Comment: It doesn't mean it is not possible.
I can connect phone to USB, I need IP addresses to make it work?

Comment: Might be possible indeed. The one figuring that out requires a developers mindset. You need to allow connections from the host into VirtualBox as well as open a port in Whonix firewall. The closest instructions (yet off-topic) is here: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/File_Transfer#SSH_into_Whonix-Gateway - And I would not start with android, USB stuff. As prerequisite knowledge and exercise figure out and learn how to configure host applications using Whonix first.

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to make usb ethernet connection via this app - you need just a simple routing VM with Tor inside, no need to set up anything else: firewall will do the whole trick.